# Mqtt paho using spring integration stops processing messages on topic over certain load requests

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt, paho

I am using Spring Integration with `mqtt-paho` version 4.0.4 For receiving MQTT messages on specified topic.

When application is receiving huge load I found that, sometimes application is dropping connection with IMA (mqtt) and this was happened three times in a span of 1 Lac record.
But it regains the connectivity and started consuming messages received there after. There were no issue in IMA re-connectivity.

There is some other issue which I faced during this testing.

When there is continuous load on application, at some point application stops receiving messages and we can see one message flashed on screen i.e.

```
May 04, 2015 2:45:29 PM org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState checkForActivity
SEVERE: gvjIpONtSpP: Timed out as no activity, keepAlive=60,000 lastOutboundActivity=1,430,730,869,017 lastInboundActivity=1,430,730,929,151
```

After this we can see that there are no messages received on application even if continuous load is pushed through utility.
This behavior I found it three times.

```
At around 40K.
At around 90K.
At around 145K.
```

There is no consistent point or figures where application actually stops receiving messages.
Please let me know if anybody has faced and solved this before .

Comment: Would you mind testing your application with the latest Spring Integration - `4.1.3` ?

Comment: Thanks for putting your valuable time, i would do that is that issue solved on that version ? do you have any idea.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. The issue really may be in the Paho, not Spring Integration. I think some test-case to reproduce would be helpful.

Comment: @Artem :yes even after upgrading to latest version the issue is still persisting meanwhile i found nearly the same issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620196/spring-integration-mqtt-subscriber-paho-stops-processing-messages). Anyway thanks for your support. I think the issue is still in paho.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue during performance testing and during MQTT Paho client performance/durability testing, before moving to production. The issue was on broker side, after settings adjustment, the IMA broker was able to consume millions of messages with no rejection.

Please look into max buffer parameter on IMA configuration web console. And overlimit behavior policy (what to do with messages published over specified threshold): reject, rollover etc.